# In Jekyll, how can I use subcategories of a variable in the layout of another collection?

Tags: jekyll, liquid

I have a collections of projects. Part of each project is a list of people who have worked on that project:

```
---
layout: project
name: Important Project
participants:
- name: julia
  role: owner
- name: paul
  role: manager
- name: chris
  role: implementer
---
```

Each of these people are in a collection themselves and have a page where their details are listed. I'd like to include the projects they've been working on and what their role was. This is my best effort but doesn't work:

```
{% for project in site.projects %}
    {% if project.participants['name'] == {{ page.name }} %}
        <p>{{ project.name }} - {{ project.participants['role'] }}</p>
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

Any suggestions are most welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I imagine that your participants items look like this :

```
---
short: julia
firstname: Julia
lastname: Last
layout: participant
---
Content
```

In your participant layout you can do :

```
<h2>Participant : {{ page.firstname }} {{ page.lastname }}</h2>
{{ content }}
<h2>Projects :</h2>
<ul>
{% for project in site.projects %}
  {% for participant in project.participants %}
    {% if participant.name == page.short %}
      <li>{{ participant.role }} in <a href="{{ site.baseurl }}{{ project.url }}">{{ project.name }}</a></li>
    {% endif %}
  {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
</ul>
```

In participant

Comment: I didn't realise I needed a second `for` statement within the other one. This makes perfect sense now, thank you so much!

Answer (score 3):

Assuming this structure:

```
# _config.yml
collections:
- people
- projects
```

Then directory structure like:

```
_projects/project1.md
_people/person1.md
_people/person2.md
```

With person1.md front-matter like:

```
---
name: julia
---
```

And the above front-matter you provided, this is how to display the list of projects and roles of each person:

```
{% for person in site.people %}

Person {{person.name}}

{% for project in site.projects%}
 {% assign person_project = project.participants | where:"name",person.name | first %}

  Project: {{project.name}}
  Role: {{person_project.role}}

{% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

Then the output looks like:

```
Person julia

Project: Important Project
Role: owner
```

Then you can improve the output as you wish, for example with a table:

```
{% for person in site.people %}
<table>
    <caption>{{person.name}} projects</caption>
    <tr>
    <th>Project</th>
    <th>Role</th>
    </tr>
    {% for project in site.projects%}
    {% assign person_project = project.participants | where:"name",person.name | first %}
    <tr>
    <td>{{project.name}}</td>
    <td>{{person_project.role}}</td>
    </tr>
    {% endfor %}
</table>
{% endfor %}
```

output:

```
julia projects 
Project             Role
Important Project   owner
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer! I marked David's as correct though because it's a shorter and cleaner solution.

Comment: To the people upvoting this and not the other answer: can you explain why? I'm of course not against upvoting good answers, I just don't see how this answer is better than the other and would love to know.